# return View with Model and go to particular anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View with multiple anchors tags. Is there a way to return a View with a model object and go to a particular anchor tag in the view?

For example, my View has anchors like this:

```
   <a name="Section1"></a>
   ...
   <a name="Section2"></a>
```

I know I can hit those anchors using:

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "myController", action = "myAction" }) + "#Section1");
```

But I don't think I can use redirect because I need to send a Model:

> ```
> return View("myAction", model); // how to go to anchor?
> ```

Comment: I have no idea what this means?

Comment: @Liam Really? Seems pretty obvious to me. I'll edit it.

Comment: that's much better! whats the action your trying to redirect to look like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can send something in you view model to view and use a javascript to scroll to that anchor. For examle suppose that you have a property named Section. You can set that in your controller and using this javascript code in your view to scroll to that anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anchor = document.getElementById('@Model.Section');
    anchor.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. I changed my anchors to specify the id rather than name: <a id="Section1"></a>

Answer (score 5):

First we need to pass the achor to our view:

**Controller:**

```
    ViewBag.Section = "register"; //#register         
    return View();
```

**View:**

```
@if (ViewBag.Section!=null)
{
    <script>
        $(function () {              
                window.location.hash = '#@ViewBag.Section';
        });
    </script>
}
```

now you can use the "how to scroll to anchor" answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906458/7149454