# Return to a certain div when a page reloaded. (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

is there a way i can return to a certain div in a view when a page is done reloading? What could I add to my controller that could achieve this when I return a view?

For example, I have a contact from at the bottom of a page, when i click submit button, the page reloads and it return to that div that the contact from is in, instead of at the top of the page.

Comment: This will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904653/return-view-with-model-and-go-to-particular-anchor-tag

Comment: Thanks, I don't have to return a model so the redirect code works great. Please answer below so I can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a named anchor to the form on the bottom of the page and in your controller redirect to your view with the anchor name at the end of the url.

This SO post has an example that you may follow: [return View with Model and go to particular anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904653/return-view-with-model-and-go-to-particular-anchor-tag)